# Updating an Activity in MS CRM via web service?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've been trying to do this all morning.  Anyone have a code snippet (C#) showing how to update an "activity" within CRM via the webservice?
I can CreateReadUpdateDelete with entities, but I'm not sure how to do it with Activities.

Can't find anything on google either...

Answer (score 5):

What are you specifically looking to update?  Basically, updating an activity is just like updating any other entity, you just have to use the `task` entity.

```
public void CloseTask(CrmService crmsvc, Guid activityid, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
    cols.Attributes = new string[] { "activityid", "statecode" };

    task tsk = (task)crmsvc.Retrieve(EntityName.task.ToString(), activityid, cols);
    if(tsk.statecode.Value != TaskState.Open)
         return;

    tsk.actualstart = new CRMDateTime();
    tsk.actualstart.value = start.ToString();
    tsk.actualend =  new CRMDateTime();
    tsk.actualend.value = end.ToString();


    crmsvc.Update(tsk);

    SetStateTaskRequest state = new SetStateTaskRequest();
    state.EntityId = activityid;
    state.TaskState = TaskState.Completed;
    state.TaskStatus = -1; // Let MS CRM decide this property;
    SetStateTaskResponse stateSet = (SetStateTaskResponse)crmsvc.Execute(state);

}
```

Edit: added some sample code.  note, I had to modify what I had to strip some proprietary code, so I don't know if this will actually compile. It's close though.

Comment: Hmm.. it says that a task with that Guid does not exist.  It is an activity.. and I know the guid is there...

Comment: Here is the actual error message:

  0x80040217
  task With Id = 84112d9e-db9b-df11-910a-00155d0a3024 Does Not Exist
  Platform

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, our activity doesn't even have those taskstates, we have "Pending""Approved""Rejected"...
I don't think "task" is going to work here..

Comment: What version are you using? This should work for 3.0 and 4.0.  Is your activity a different, custom entity?

Comment: Custom Activity, sorry, can't say anymore (NDA)

Comment: That's a good enough answer. Good luck with it, I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

We can also update a Custom Workflow Activity Using Assembly Versioning. Below link gives more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328011.aspx

Comment: This appears to be about activity entity records, not CWAs. Also, using assembly versioning breaks the existing workflows, at least in CRM 4.